# ImageIO framework shows error loading on device

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using SDwebimage for lazyloading in my app.It uses ImageIo framework,It works perfectly in simulator.But when try to run in devices it shows an error "could not build module ImageIO".Any idea what is the reason for this error which works in simulator.Thanks

The error shows at `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`  could not build module ImageIO

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.